Getting "Array to string conversion" error when creating a custom field type in WooCommerce
I'm developing a custom WooCommerce shipping method and trying to create a custom field type called multiselect_with_limits. This custom field type should allow selecting multiple neighborhoods and specifying a minimum order limit for each one.
However, when I try to use this custom field type, I get the following error:
Warning: Array to string conversion in /wp-includes/formatting.php on line 1096

function woocommerce_form_field_multiselect_with_limits( $key, $args, $value ) {
    // Eğer multiselect değerleri array ise işle
    if ( is_array( $value ) ) {
        $value = implode(',', $value);
    }

    $field = '<select multiple="multiple" name="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '[]" id="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" class="wc-enhanced-select">';
    
    foreach ( $args['options'] as $option_key => $option_label ) {
        $selected = in_array( $option_key, explode(',', $value) ) ? 'selected' : '';
        $field .= '<option value="' . esc_attr( $option_key ) . '" ' . $selected . '>' . esc_html( $option_label ) . '</option>';
        $limit = isset($args['value_limits'][$option_key]) ? esc_attr($args['value_limits'][$option_key]) : '';
        $field .= '<input type="number" name="' . esc_attr( $key . '_limit_' . $option_key ) . '" value="' . $limit . '" placeholder="' . __( 'Min Limit', 'enravo-shipping' ) . '" style="width: 60px; margin-left: 5px;">';
    }

    $field .= '</select>';
    return $field;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_form_field_multiselect_with_limits', 'woocommerce_form_field_multiselect_with_limits', 10, 3);


    public function init() {
        // Load the settings API
        $this->instance_form_fields = array(
            'enabled' => array(
                'title'   => __( 'Enable/Disable', 'enravo-shipping' ),
                'type'    => 'checkbox',
                'label'   => __( 'Enable this shipping method', 'enravo-shipping' ),
                'default' => 'yes',
            ),
            'allowed_district' => array(
                'title'       => __( 'Allowed District', 'enravo-shipping' ),
                'type'        => 'select',
                'description' => __( 'The district where this shipping method is available.', 'enravo-shipping' ),
                'default'     => '',
                'options'     => $this->get_districts_by_city($this->get_option('allowed_city')),
                'class'       => 'wc-enhanced-select',
                'desc_tip'    => true,
            ),
            'allowed_neighborhood' => array(
                'title'       => __( 'Allowed Neighborhood', 'enravo-shipping' ),
                'type'        => 'multiselect_with_limits',
                'description' => __( 'The neighborhoods where this shipping method is available and their minimum order limits.', 'enravo-shipping' ),
                'default'     => '',
                'options'     => $this->get_neighborhoods_by_district($this->get_option('allowed_district')),
                'desc_tip'    => true,
            ),
        );

        // Save settings
        add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_shipping_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );
    }


WordPress version: 6.6.1
WooCommerce version: 9.1.2
PHP version: 8.2.1
I expected WooCommerce to correctly render the custom field with the dropdown options and input fields and to process the form data without errors.

Which line is it? Warning: Array to string conversion in /wp-includes/formatting.php on line 1096

function wp_check_invalid_utf8( $text, $strip = false ) {
1096 line>> $text = (string) $text;
             if ( 0 === strlen( $text ) ) {

return '';
}

Then text is an array. Do a conversion instead. $text = is_array($text) ? implode('', $text) : (string)$text;, but don't change a wordpress core file, do it before you pass it.

Why converting $value to a string if the only usage is explode(',',$value) (as array). And then you do the conversion in each loop run.
